# jQuery Plugin to perform Date manipulations

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, javascript

Am looking for a jQuery utility that will let me do date manipulations. 
eg:
1) Add x no. of days to a date and get a new Date.
2) For given a date, gives the corresponding week of the year
3) Find no. of days between 2 dates
4) Find no. of weeks between 2 dates
5) Find no. of months between 2 dates

Is there a jQuery plugin that has these generic functions built in ?

(Am not looking for any UI plugin)

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest [DateJS](http://www.datejs.com/) even if it's not a jQuery plugin.

Comment: This is just incredible. Thanks for sharing this awesome API.

Comment: Though i was looking for a jquery plugin, I think i will have to settle with date.js