# Is there a jQuery time/calendar plugin for manipulating dates?

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, jquery-plugins

I need to work with dates, adding/subtracting hours and days. With the JavaScript date object this is a bit difficult, since there is only get/set and no add method.

Is there a plugin that ease this work, with a functions like `add("2d3h")` (add 2 days and 3 hours)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery Plugin to perform Date manipulations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2997785/jquery-plugin-to-perform-date-manipulations)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [DateJS](http://www.datejs.com/), far the best for manipulating dates in JS, I think

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to use:

[Datejs](http://www.datejs.com/)