# Datepicker giving different result in IE and Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, date, datepicker

I have two Datepickers and based on the date selection of first datepicker, the second datepicker should show allow user to choose a date within 1 year of the date selected in the first datepicker. The code I am using is working perfectly for Chrome but it is giving different result in IE11. When I use the alert method to view the date, in **Chrome** I get the result "**Wed Oct 10 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)**" whereas in **IE** the result is "**Wed Oct 10 1918 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)**"

```
$('.datepicker1').datepicker({
    dateFormat: "mm/dd/y",
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    yearRange: "-10:+10",
    showOn: "both",
    buttonText: "<i class='fa fa-calendar'></i>",
    onSelect: function (date) {


        var selectedDate = new Date(date);
        alert(selectedDate)
        var date = new Date(Date.parse(selectedDate));

        date.setFullYear(date.getFullYear() + 1);

        var newDate = date.toDateString();

        newDate = new Date(Date.parse(newDate));

        $(".datepicker2").datepicker("option", "maxDate", newDate);



    }
});

$('.datepicker2').datepicker({
    dateFormat: "mm/dd/y",
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    showOn: "both",
    buttonText: "<i class='fa fa-calendar'></i>"
});
```

Below is the Razor syntax used

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.date1, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "datepicker1 form-control", placeholder = "00/00/00", @readonly = "readonly" } })

@Html.EditorFor(m => m.date2, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "datepicker2 form-control", placeholder = "00/00/00", @readonly = "readonly" } })
```

Can anyone help me figure out where I went wrong? Seems like Date.Parse might not be working as expected in IE, do we have a workaround? Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the value of *date* in `new Date(date)`? Your problem is most likely the year: `dateFormat: "mm/dd/y"` should probably be `dateFormat: "mm/dd/yyyy"`. Two digit years are treated as 20th century (i.e. "18" is "1918" not "2018").

Comment: PS. Using the built-in parser for non–standard strings is strongly recommended against. Manually parse strings with a small function or use a library, see [*Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results)

Comment: @RobG my requirement is to show the date in mm/dd/y format i.e 10/16/18 as per current date. I won't be facing the issue mentioned in the question if I used mm/dd/yy. As of now I will be trying to parse it manually and will update.

Comment: Cool, seems UI presentation is getting in the way of parsing and processing. A parser is 2 lines of code: split then give the bits to the Date constructor, e.g. `let b = s.split(/\D/); return new Date('20' + b[2], b[0]-1, b[1])` assuming all years are 21st century and *s* is a string like "09/14/09" for 14-Sep-2009.

Comment: @RobG big help. Since I won't be dealing with past dates, this solution suits me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rob actually helped me reach the solution, since he posted the answer in comments, I am mentioning it as separate answer. My requirement was to show the date as mm/dd/yy format but 2 digits years are treated as 20th Century in IE, that's why I was getting 1918 in IE for date 10/16/18. So I wrote a small parser method as advised by Rob.

```
function parseDate(input) {
    var parts = input.split('/');
    // new Date(year, month [, day [, hours[, minutes[, seconds[, ms]]]]])
    return new Date('20' + parts[2], parts[0] - 1, parts[1]);
}
```

Use the method in the onSelect event of the first datepicker

```
onSelect: function (date) {

        var parsedDate = parseDate(date);

        var date = new Date(Date.parse(parsedDate));

        date.setFullYear(date.getFullYear() + 1);

        var newDate = date.toDateString();

        newDate = new Date(Date.parse(newDate));

        $(".datepicker2").datepicker("option", "maxDate", newDate);


    }
```

Since I am only dealing with present dates, I won't have to worry about dates belonging to 1900's.

Comment: Treating 2 digit years as 20c is per [*ECMA-262 §20.3.2.1 4.h*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/#sec-date-year-month-date-hours-minutes-seconds-ms): `If y is not NaN and 0 ≤ ToInteger(y) ≤ 99, let yr be 1900+ToInteger(y);`.  ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The 2-digit date conversion which resulting in 20th century year problem with [`Date.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) (and `Date` constructor) is a known behavior in IE (and Edge, see [this issue](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/11611685/)) as provided below:

> Firefox 49 changed the parsing of 2-digit years to be aligned with the
>   Google Chrome browser instead of Internet Explorer. Now, 2-digit years
>   that are less than 50 are parsed as 21st century years.

As for workaround in IE 11 and Edge, you can avoid `Date` constructor for parsing date string by using [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/) with specified 2-digit year format conversion to 4-digit year as provided below:

```
var date = new Date(moment(selectedDate, "M/D/YY").format("M/D/YYYY"));

newDate = new Date(moment(newDate, "M/D/YY").format("M/D/YYYY"));
```

Note that you can still create your own parser for 2-to-4 digit year conversion, but it may takes more time to split date components and rejoining them into `Date` constructor.

Related issue:

[Converting (formatting) 2-digit date to a 4-digit date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14630613/converting-formatting-2-digit-date-to-a-4-digit-date)